# How to keep a SECRET_KEY secret in Django?

Tags: python, django, encryption, key, secret-key

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/) suggests keeping the SECRET_KEY in environmental variables rather than in the settings.py file.

Why is this considered safer? The environmental variables are plain text-files which offer the same level of protection as settings.py. Even if the file rw permissions are set to root-only, I assume that this is not hard to break.

My question is: **which other options are there to store the SECRET_KEY?**

Or the master key used for encryption. From [django-encrypted-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-secrets/):

> django-encrypted-secrets works by using a key (stored locally in master.key file or read from the **environment variable** DJANGO_MASTER_KEY) and reading/writing secrets to the encrypted file secrets.yml.enc.

If there is no other option than a plain text-file or environmental variable stored locally. How can this one be protected properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's considered safer is because you should have your settings file in git or some other VCS to have consistent development environments, but your secrets should be outside of it. This way, even developers don't have the production secrets if they don't need them.

It doesn't need any extra protection as long as you're careful about how you deploy your code, who can access the servers, etc.

Your question also asks about other methods, so...

You could encrypt it like you have there, but this will always require a master key that also needs securing somehow.

Another option is to use a text file on the server.

A good option if you want to encrypt the secrets is to store them encrypted in your continuous integration solution, which injects them into the environment at deploy time. Travis CI, GitHub Actions, more or less any CI solution can do this.

But in general, just keeping it out of VCS and limiting the access to the secrets is usually good enough.

Comment: +1. FWIW I use a local text file and generate it as part of the Ansible build process for a VM. `SECRET_KEY` only really seems relevant to Django and I couldn’t find a reason to keep a master copy of it anywhere, inside or outside of source control.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Still, it seems a bit strange that all the options focus on protecting the passwords from spreading during the development stage rather than from attackers entering to your deployed site.

Comment: If someone has access to the server and enough to read those files, you have way bigger problems already. The app needs things like database credentials in plaintext in order to connect to the resources, there's no real way around that. Even if you encrypted them somewhere, they will still be in plaintext _somewhere_, either in a file, in the environment, or in memory. At that point there's nothing you can really do to stop a determined attacker from getting that information, ...

Comment: ... Even if they are encrypted on the server and only visible in memory, the server needs to be able to read the decryption key to decrypt them, which needs to be readable. If someone can read the files on the server, they can read the decryption key too and still get the decrypted credentials.